# Database connection Laravel in Model QueryException Array to string conversion "(SQL: CALL to prc_users_insert(12,,1,,,akhtar,munir,,,))"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In User model I have created this method and I have simply call this method in controller to just insert this dummy data but I get 
          this error array to string conversion, I might be missing something 
          here, and yes I have used stored procedures for inserting into database and in database the procedure is working fine, any help would be appreciated Thanks.

```
      public function insert(){
      $data = DB::insert(
      "CALL prc_users_insert(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
      ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
      array(getdate(),1,'','',101,'','admin',12345,'akhtar','munir',
      45,'','','akhtar@gmail.com','','','','','','','',
      2,'','','','','',1,1,1,1,1,1,1,'Y'));

      print_r($data);
      }
```

In controller I have written this code:

```
      function usertData(){
       $user = new UserModel();
       $user->insert();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getdate() function returns an assoc. array, thus generating the error.
Depending on what is the desired format of the date, you can either choose to insert a timestamp with "now()" or a date time format using date('Y-m-d H:i:s') or what is might fit your needs

Comment: yeah its working but now it gives me incorrect integer value TEN_ID 101, that i have given in the procedure

Comment: You will have to provide more info on the error, i assume in one of your columns 'TEN_ID' the input expected is integer and you try to insert a non integer value.
Again, provide more info on the structure and the sql query  you are running to be able to get some help